# Whats the best application to monitor bandwidth usage on iis6?

Tags: iis-6, sql, bandwidth

Our hosting company is currently stinging us for bandwidth usage on our web servers. At the moment, we have no idea where the bandwidth is going! Does anyone have any good recommendations of programs to monitor the bandwidth usage for individual sites on iis 6? Or in fact, for everything coming in and out of the machine in case its not actually iis using the bandwidth. The server also runs sql and some of our sites access external databases (would this sort of data show up in iis logs?).

Ideally we wanted to stay away from analysing log files as we do not have a lot of space for storing them (the main server that is causing the bandwidth usage on our account is pretty busy) and log files will not show bandwidth usage outside of iis but if there isn't anything else, logging will at least tell us if the problem is within iis or elsewhere. We are looking at http://www.livebandwidth.com , does anyone have any experience with using this in a production environment?

Thanks

Chris Foot

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using the built-in Windows Performance Monitor (perfmon.exe)?  It's free and works well.  You can use it to log some pretty granular stats on IIS.  And if you don't want to store the logfiles on the actual monitored server, you can always run perfmon on another box and connect to it across the network.

Answer (score 0):

You've no doubt looked at Live Bandwidth more than I have.  But, I think the difference between what you described and what Live Bandwidth gives you is specific knowledge of IIS.  If you want to see network traffic for the server, there are lots of tools that can do this.  If your intent is to get insight into what IIS is doing specifically, not only network, but overall, you will need to look at a few other approaches.  If it's IIS specifically you want to gain knowledge of you probably are going to need to see it from within IIS.  You might start by checking out appfirst.  They do this.

Note that the real work done by IIS is in the kernel.  The traffic you want to see is in handled in kernel mode for IIS, that's a big reason why you don't see a lot of options.